# 301 Redirect PDF File

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I am having troubles redirecting a single pdf file to a new location.

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase /

#REDIRECT QR CODE LINKS TO A NEW SOURCE
RedirectMatch 301 http://www.sampledomain.eu/assets/fm/download/en-gb/Technical%20documentation/General%20information/Substrates%20table%20Sample.pdf http://www.sampledomain.eu/assets/fm/download/en-gb/Technical%20documentation/Information/01_General%20information/02_Substrates%20table%20Sample.pdf
```

note there are spaces in the URL

I also tried this without success:

```
#REDIRECT QR CODE LINKS TO A NEW SOURCE
RedirectMatch 301 ^/assets/fm/download/en-gb/Technical%20documentation/General%20information/Substrates%20table%20Sample.pdf$ http://www.sampledomain.eu/assets/fm/download/en-gb/Technical%20documentation/Information/01_General%20information/02_Substrates%20table%20Sample.pdf
```

how can I make it work?

Answer (score 1):

`%20` is decoded by browser/web server into space characters.

Use this rule with correct regex:

```
RedirectMatch 301 "^/assets/fm/download/en-gb/Technical documentation/General information/Substrates table Sample.pdf$" http://www.sampledomain.eu/assets/fm/download/en-gb/Technical%20documentation/Information/01_General%20information/02_Substrates%20table%20Sample.pdf
```